# Python file closes immediately when doing file handling operations

Tags: python, file-handling

I have a python file that analyses two .txt files, then writes on another .txt file the analysis of these two files. The thing is, running the .py file on the IDE (PyCharm), windows terminal/command prompt works fine, but when double clicking on the actual file and opening using the python interpreter on my computer, it only briefly displays a dark screen with the path of the python interpreter on the top bar. I found that when the python file doesn't deal with any files at all, that is, using

```
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    # file handling
```

or

```
f = open("file.txt","r")
# code
f.close()
```

the file works fine. However, when using any of these, the python file closes almost immediately after opening.

I have tried using another IDE, putting in `prompt = input("Enter to exit")` or `while` loops to keep the window open, but again, the window only stays open when it's not dealing with files for some reason. I have also tested to see if PyCharm had something going on that stopped the python program from running independently, and only within the virtual environment, but that isn't the case when I tested it with another .py file that had no file handling inside a PyCharm project.

What is causing the python file to close when handling files, despite using various methods to keep the window open, and how do I fix it?

Comment: It's possible that when running the script through the interpreter (double-clicking), the current working directory is different from when you run it in your IDE, which means the interpreter may not be able to resolve the relative file path to `"file.txt"`, resulting in an unhandled exception, which terminates the script. You can try providing the absolute path to the file instead to see if it makes a difference, or you can try printing `os.cwd()` and pausing the script (via `input()`) before your script does any IO with files to confirm the current working directory is what you expect.

Comment: You can use the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) to log errors to a file or perhaps the system log, then wrap your code in a try/except block to catch errors and log them. Your current code doesn't have good error handling, and something like this will help.Generally, your design needs to include what to do when your files don't exist. When you add that code, it should help you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: So I found that the program's cwd when being run was in C:\WINDOWS\system32 (not where the files are stored) so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would use the [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_file) to verify the file actually exists via a defined absolute path as opposed to relative path:

```
from pathlib import Path

my_file = Path("/path/to/file")
if my_file.is_file()
    # file exists
```

Alternatively, you can use try-except blocks to check. If the error is a FileNotFoundError, your program will gracefully terminate as a checked exception.

```
try:
    my_absolute_path = my_file.resolve(strict=True)
except FileNotFoundError:
    # File does not exist in your specified directory
else:
    # File exists
```